# Splitting routes with prefix not working in Play 2.7 (worked in 2.6)

Tags: scala, playframework, play-framework-2.7

Our project uses multiple routes files.

The conf/routes file contains something like:

```
/some/stuff
...

-> /api/admin       admin.Routes
-> /api/user          user.Routes
```

We then have conf/admin.routes and conf/user.routes files, which contain the prefixed API routes.

I’m trying to upgrade from Play 2.6 (where this setup has worked fine, as well as on earlier versions), to Play 2.7. When compiling I get the error:

```
[error] /usr/src/backend/conf/admin.routes:401: value concatPrefix is not a member of object play.api.routing.Router
[error] GET            /myAdminRoute                                                                        @com.my.some.controllers.MyControl.list()
[error] /usr/src/backend/conf/user.routes:140: value concatPrefix is not a member of object play.api.routing.Router
[error] GET            /myUserRoute                                                 @com.my.other.controllers.MyControl.list()
```

Looking at Play migration for 2.7:

- I’m not using StaticRoutesGenerator https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/Migration27#StaticRoutesGenerator-removed
- Looks suspicious: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/Migration27#StaticRoutesGenerator-removed Router#withPrefix should always add a prefix`. But I’m just using Play conf/routes, so I’m not sure what I should be changing?

I assume the issue is because of that Router withPrefix change, but I’m not sure how to interpret it in terms of what I need to update. Has anyone else had this issue with Play 2.7?

Comment: Are you sure you are not mixing different Play versions somehow? `concatPrefix` should indeed be a member of object `play.api.routing.Router`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just had another play with this, the first time was a few weeks ago - and I'm not getting the same error. I can repro if I start again and forget the SBT `unlock; reload; lock` cycle, which is probably the mistake I made before. This leaves me with Play 2.6 libraries installed with the Play 2.7 plugin.